# Doing the job on Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, development-environment

So, I've got a new laptop, and sadly, it has Windows 8 pre-installed with no options to downgrade. Which got me thinking, maybe I can stick with Windwows 8? What will I loose?

My question is - do any of software developers use Windows 8 on every-day basis to do the job and are there any problems?

Like, maybe some software isn't supported by Windows 8.1, or some languages support is difficult to add. Everything's ok with Ruby, PHP, any other web-development tools and servers, MYSQL and other databases? What about mobile development (which I will we doing), any problems is this department? While working, did you stuble upon any specific situations that got you thinkg 'Damn, I hate Win8, wish it would be Win7' (except for MetroUI stuff).

The main question, I think, would be apps compatability and stuff like MinGW and other linux environment tools support on Windows.

Any ideas?

Comment: StackOverflow is not a discussion forum. We expect programming questions here.

Comment: Well, where would you recommend asking a question on software development? At last, it's the place where all software developers are

Comment: Audience may be right, but the format isn't fit for SO. Your question is a) primarly opinion based and b) too broad. If you have a *particular* problem with a development tool on Windows 8, you are welcome to ask.

Comment: I'll let the audience decide. You are free to downvote the question, as you probably did already=)

Comment: So, answering to my own question even if it's closed already. Windows 8.1 was an awful experience after >6 months of use. I had to disable SSD - it was freezing the PC completely and there are video driver issues that result in memory problems, still unresolved by Microsoft. All software seemed to be working, except maybe for Skype, that is still buggy on 8.1 to this day. So after all, I think it would be better to go back to Win7

Answer (score 2):

I can't say for `MinGW` or other linux-related environment tools because I don't use them at work, but I can say that everything I've needed has been working flawlessly in Windows 8. I've even recently upgraded to 8.1 and everything has continued working just fine.

I use MyEclipse 8.0, MySQL and Tomcat 6.

Never had compatibility issues and I'm very pleased with the OS.